# JQuery floating menu bar, scroll position and delay

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm making a menu bar and im fairly new to JQuery. I want the menu bar to be a delayed on scroll down, but on scroll up i want it to stick to the top of the browser window, without delay. The delay is now the same on both sides and when scrolled to top, there is no delay.

I hope someone can help me :)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var speed = 1000;
var speedtop = 0;
var menu = $('nav#header');
var offset = menu.offset().top;
var menuStartPos = menu.position().top;
var top_offset = 0;

updateFloatingMenu(); //we don't have this just yet

$(window).scroll(function(){
    updateFloatingMenu();
});

function updateFloatingMenu(){
    var scrollAmount = $(document).scrollTop();
    var newPosition = menuStartPos + scrollAmount;

    if(scrollAmount > offset){
        var topPos = (newPosition-offset) + top_offset;
        menu.stop().animate({top: topPos}, speed);
    }else{
        menu.stop().animate({top: menuStartPos}, speedtop);
    }
};
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a class to your css:

```
#header.fixed {
    position:fixed;
    top: 0 !important; /* important, to override inline style-tag */
}
```

Add this class to the menu when scrolling up, to always fix it on the top of the page

```
var offset = 0;

function updateFloatingMenu(){
    var scrollAmount = $(document).scrollTop();

    if (scrollAmount > offset){
        menu.stop().removeClass('fixed').animate({'top': scrollAmount}, speed);
    } else {
        menu.stop().addClass('fixed')
        menu.css('top', scrollAmount); // Set top here so it's in the right place when reverting scroll
    }

    offset = scrollAmount; // Update current offset
}
```